# Can someone explain what /^(\-|\+)?([0-9]+|Infinity)$/ is?

Tags: javascript, regex

```
/^(\-|\+)?([0-9]+|Infinity)$/
```

I've seen this multiple times when I'm looking to filter things. There are many variations but it usually always starts with (/ then something. Recently I found this as a suggestion to help parse a string and make sure it has only numbers in it. On Mozilla's js page for RegExp I found some other operators but it didn't include nearly all that are above.

Comment: Also see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736/learning-regular-expressions

Comment: http://regexper.com/#%2F%5E(%5C-%7C%5C%2B)%3F(%5B0-9%5D%2B%7CInfinity)%24%2F

Comment: Lately I discovered [Regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/kS1mL0/1) an Web 2.0 site to discover, debug and test regular expressions. It also has a single step debugger.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this regex mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a regular expression. The one you pasted would match a positive/negative whole number, or match the word infinity. In short, a regular expression is:

> A regular expression (regex or regexp for short) is a special text
>   string for describing a search pattern. You can think of regular
>   expressions as wildcards on steroids.

http://www.regular-expressions.info/

You often see regular expressions written as `/expression_here/` because these slashes in many programming languages are a shorthand way for developers to build regular expression objects.

You could create a simple expression to match a number with something like:

```
/^[0-9]*$/.test('44') // returns true
```

and

```
/^[0-9]*$/.test('asdasd') // returns false
```

Expressions like these and like the one you've pasted are parsed and turned into little machines (called [finite state machines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine)). the entire purpose of the machine is to determine if a string is a match for the expression the machine represents, or if it is not a match. You can then feed a string into such a machine and it will spit back the answer to you.

In our example above, we feed the strings `44` and `asdasd` into a regular expression `/^[0-9]*$/` using the `test` method, and it returns `true` because `44` matches the expression and `false` for `asdasd` because it does not match.

We can break up the regular expression that you included in your post as well:

`^` means that the regular expression has to match starting from the VERY beginning of the string

`(\-|\+)` means start at the beginning of the string and match either `-` or `+`, the question mark means this part is optional

`[0-9]+|Infinity` means "match one or more numbers from 0 to 9", OR (`|`) match the text `Infinity`

`$` means, "and then require that the string ends here"

Answer (score 3):

It's a [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) that will match positive/negative natural numbers or `Infinity`.

```
/^(\-|\+)?([0-9]+|Infinity)$/
```

`^(\-|\+)` - Match the beginning of the string for either the `-` or `+` literal character(s).

`?` - The preceding expression, which are the `-`/`+` characters, are optional. In other words, the expression can be matched 0 or 1 times.

`([0-9]+|Infinity)$` - The end of the string should be 1 or more digits or the string `Infinity`.

```
// Matches:
'-100'.match(/^(\-|\+)?([0-9]+|Infinity)$/);
'+100'.match(/^(\-|\+)?([0-9]+|Infinity)$/);
'Infinity'.match(/^(\-|\+)?([0-9]+|Infinity)$/);
```

```
// Does NOT match:
'5%'.match(/^(\-|\+)?([0-9]+|Infinity)$/);
'20/1'.match(/^(\-|\+)?([0-9]+|Infinity)$/);
'NaN'.match(/^(\-|\+)?([0-9]+|Infinity)$/);
```